# Is this a bug in the implementation of Coroutines TS shipped with Clang 6.0?

Tags: c++, clang, implementation, c++-coroutine

Below is a reproducible example:

```
AnyFutureWithInnerPromise<void> f()
{
    char arr[16]; // crash here due to segmentation fault
    co_return;
}

int main()
{
    f().get();
}
```

gdb tells me, the crash line is:

```
movaps XMMWORD PTR [rcx+0xb8],xmm0
```

The cause is that `movaps` requires its operands to be 128-bit aligned, but `XMMWORD PTR [rcx+0xb8]` is not the case.

If I change the code as follows:

```
AnyFutureWithInnerPromise<void> f()
{
    std::uint64_t n; // add 8-bytes to make arr 128-bit aligned
    char arr[16]; // ok now        
    co_return;
}
```

The new assembly instruction is:

```
movaps XMMWORD PTR [rcx+0xc0],xmm0
```

**Is this a bug in the implementation of Coroutines TS shipped with Clang 6.0?**

Comment: Yes. <10 more characters to go>.